Create discount in shopify with Graph Ql
I'm trying to create a Discount with a fixedAmount but i've some trouble with amout one side the problem is the MoneyV2 type and on the other side this is currencyCode not available
and often the same error like  : "Variable $basicCodeDiscount of type DiscountCodeBasicInput! was provided invalid value for customerGets.value.amount (Field is not defined on DiscountCustomerGetsValueInput), customerGets.value.currencyCode (Field is not defined on DiscountCustomerGetsValueInput)"
        value = new { amount = new { amount = discount.Value, currencyCode = "EUR" } }; } var query = $@"mutation discountCodeBasicCreate($basicCodeDiscount: DiscountCodeBasicInput!) {{ discountCodeBasicCreate(basicCodeDiscount: $basicCodeDiscount) {{ codeDiscountNode {{ codeDiscount {{ ... on DiscountCodeBasic {{ title codes(first: 10) {{ nodes {{ code }} }} startsAt endsAt customerSelection {{ ... on DiscountCustomerAll {{ allCustomers }} ... on DiscountCustomers {{ customers {{ id email }} }} }} customerGets {{ value{{  ... on DiscountAmount {{ amount }} }} }} appliesOncePerCustomer usageLimit }} }} }} }} }}";
Many Thanks for helping :)
